# Knowing XSD to use to validate XML config file for program

Tags: python, xml, deployment, xsd

I know how to write XML and XSD files but this is the first time I've actually used them in development. What is the point of the attribute [schemaLocation](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_schema.asp) (e.g. `<note xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com note.xsd">`) because it can't be used to load an XSD file the XML file is supposed to adhere to?

Here is my situation. The project requirements are to have an input XML configuration file, and to have an XSD file for it. When the program is run, it first validates the XML against the XSD schema. My question is, how is the program made aware of the XSD file? Is it passed by a command line argument, obtained through parsing the string of `schemaLocation` or can it be hard coded into the program as the schema for the input file will never change (or at least it's name wouldn't change)?

What's the "common practice" for validating an xml config file for a program?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the point of the attribute `schemaLocation`

The `xsd:schema/@schemaLocation` attribute provides a hint as to the location of the XSD to use for this XML document.

> because it can't be used to load an XSD file the XML file is supposed to adhere to?

Yes, it really can be used to locate and load the XSD file that the XML is supposed to adhere to.

> My question is, how is the program made aware of the XSD file?

The most common way is to use `schemaLocation` for namespaced XML and `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` for XML without namespaces.  Conformant XML parsers typically by default will use these attributes to locate an XSD.

> Is it passed by a command line argument, obtained through parsing the
>   string of schemaLocation or can it be hard coded into the program as
>   the schema for the input file will never change (or at least it's name
>   wouldn't change)?

All of these options are possible, but as mentioned above, `schemaLocation` and `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` are most common.

Comment: "Yes, it really can be used to locate and load the XSD file that the XML is supposed to adhere to." How? If I have the function `validateXML(schema, xmlFile)` how do I get the name of the XSD file and pass it as `schema`?

Comment: The XML parser will read it from `schemaLocation` or `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.  Just be sure that you've configured it to validate.  For Xerces-J-based parsers, see https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#validation.schema